# Carousel with View not just images in android

Tags: imageview, carousel, viewgroup

How to have a carousel with a view not just images?It should contain views which has its own functionality. which is not interlinked with the neighbour views.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a carousel with HTML content and not just and image slider?

If so you may want to look at something like [anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/). This plugin is quite old but may suit your needs.